# Влияет ли размер сетки (Grid/Tilemap) и количество на ней тайлов на производительность игры?

Tags: unity3d

Я рисую уровень по сетке. То есть создаю Grid-Tilemap-Rentangular.
Выставляю размер сетки 100x100. И далее рисую по ней тайлами, размером 100x100.

Но я могу создать сетку размером  10x10. И рисовать по ней тайлами, размером 10x10. Тогда на уровне будет в 10 раз больше тайлов.

**Влияет ли размер сетки и количество на ней тайлов на производительность игры?**
Для юнити это имеет значение или движок при компиляции объединит тайлы в один большой рисунок и ему всё равно как там было нарисовано?

Что насчет коллайдеров? Я рисую "землю" тайлами и добавляю к тайлмепу компонент 2д тайлмеп коллайдер.
Теперь мой игрок не провалится сквозь землю.

При добавлении 2д тайлмеп коллайдер, юнити обводит границы **каждого тайла** зеленым цветом.
Чем больше тайлов, тем больше границ. Это как разрезать большой пирог на несколько кусков.

Это как то влияет или юнити также понимает, что невозможно пересечь некоторые границы и просто упростит коллайдер - соберет из кучи маленьких один большой?

Answer (score 1):

- если спрайты всех тайлов на одной текстуре то видеокарта отрисует их за один `DrawCall`. Количество вызавов влияет на производительность, их можно смотреть в [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerRendering.html) <kbd>Draw calls:</kbd> и даже что именно отрисовал каждый вызов.
- 100 или 10 разных спрайтов на 1000 тайлов, если все спрайты на одной текстуре, это не существенная разница.
- отрисовываются только тайлы в кадре.

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить. У меня 2D игра. Мне надо нарисовать прямоугольник длинной 100 пикселей. Для этого я создаю прямоугольную сетку, с ячейкой 100 пикселей. Создаю тайлсет (png картинку) на которой рисую прямоугольник длинной 100 пикселей. Загружаю картинку и разрезаю её в юнити. Перетаскиваю на палитру и рисую по сетке. Но я также могу сделать всё это с картинкой в 10 пикселей. То есть, в первом случае, у меня на уровне нарисован 1 тайл с тайлсета, во втором 10  тайлов (одинаковых). Разницы нет?